# You accept a contract conditions or approve them?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Suppose you are talking to your close friend after finishing a commercial meeting which was established in order to come to an agreement with a partner company's directing manager; I was wondering if you could let me know which one of the following self-made sentences sound more natural to you:

> - No matter how much I persisted he would not **accept** the conditions of the contract.
> - No matter how much I persisted he would not **approve** the conditions of the contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meanings of these two words do overlap, but the principal meaning of the two words is as follows:

[accept](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/accept) means  **to say yes to an offer or invitation**

[approve](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/approve) means  **to officially agree to something**

Here is an example to explain the difference.

> You work for company A, and you have written a contract with company B. You show it to your boss, who **approves** the contract. You then present it to the boss in company B, who **accepts** the contract.

I think that **accept** is probably the better word to use in this case, though both words are satisfactory.